# Monitor user activities of an application

Tags: java, mysql

I have a java application. My application has 'n' number of users with 3 type of roles (r1, r2 and r3). I need user's daily usage report. In other words, I need to find user count (by role) who are using my application daily.

I need user count in daily basis as, 
users of role1 - 456, 
users of role2 - 3463 etc..

How can I do this. I am  planning to store users login date in a separate table. So that I can get the users count easily by date. But storage space required for these data in database may be too high.

Can anyone suggest me whether the above process is an efficient way or is there any predefined (opensource or paid) tools to track user counts (by role) and activities. Or is there any other efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is good. If all that you need is user logged-in count that's good. I think that keeping logs when user logged-in is good. I understand that you don't need to track activities. You can keep data in a table with user login, sign-in date etc. If data gets too large use non-relatonal database like MongoDB or aggregate data for last month/year etc. I mean to create aggregated rows like `(day:2012-08-02, role:Role1, count:123),(day:2012-08-02, role:role2, count:453)` etc. Just keep counts of role for each day and delete 'raw' data.

Comment: Hi.Thanks. Then I will proceed with this. But just to know, do you have any idea about some external tools to monitor users activity of an application?

Comment: Probably you can use googleanalytics for this. Just pass login event with username to googleanalytics.

Comment: Ok let me check that. Thank you.

Comment: Actually you need to send user role not name.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some simple Database for these purposes: SQLite would fit, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that only count is required based on 3 (or more) roles, then I would suggest following approach would save a lot of space. (Assuming it is Oracle database)

- Add a new 'counter' column in your table.
- Create a sequence.
- Write a trigger which will execute on 'update' of your table. In this trigger.
- In this trigger acquire NEXTVAL from sequence and update to 'counter' column.
- Daily drop this sequence and create again to resent the counter

In this approach you will only have rows equal to number of roles. Before dropping sequence, retrieve the 'counter' value for each role, then drop it to reset. You could further automate this whole process.